# Stuck in creating mandrill web hooks for inbound emails in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, mandrill

here is the code what i have did so far

```
var e = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["mandrill_events"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["mandrill_events"]))
            {
                string json = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["mandrill_events"].Replace("mandrill_events=", string.Empty);
                var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OppmannCommon.MailEvent>>(json);
                //var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<OppmannCommon.MailEvent>>(json);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                {
                    foreach (var mailEvent in events)
                    {
                        //var message = mailEvent.Msg;
                        var objCommonWebCommunicator = new CommonWebCommunicator();
                        objCommonWebCommunicator.HandleMandrillWebhook(mailEvent);
                        //... Do stuff with email message here...
                    }
                }
            }
            // MUST do this or Mandrill will not accept your webhook!
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

This is giving me `HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.` when i am testing webhook.

if i comment out all code just return status code then test is working fine.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695846/how-to-handle-mandrill-webhooks-in-net

Comment: yes i am using this code. now i have resolved this error.but i am not able to get headers when event type is hard bounce or soft bounce but for inbound emails it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question but your last comment above (*"..but I am not able to get headers when event type is hard bounce or soft bounce but for inbound emails it is working fine."*) leads me to believe that you have overlooked the final (and easiest!) step: **Have you Added the Webhook for emails with negative events?**  I have attached a screenshot of my functioning webhook.

[image: Screenshot of my functioning webhook]

Setting up different webhooks for positive/negative events is a great plan since it allows for you to manipulate the events with minimal effort (just route to your different Methods).

Does this help you?

Comment: At that time i was getting responses from inbound emails.But i was not able to get headers in my web hook.So i passed required values as tags in my emails.